# PHP comparison operator error

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

I use "Ampps and vagrant "Scotch Box" as local server my problem is that `==` and `===` operators works as I expect but on hosting they behave so different for example I check site status and user role like this

```
if($status ===0 and $request->user()->role!==1){

}else{

}
```

this if statement works perfect on local both vagrant and Ammps, but on my hosting always else part works , is there any PHP settings for setting this difference?

Comment: Nope, the `==` and `===` operators are language constructs that cannot be altered in their behavior.

Comment: Then do some debugging of the values of `$status` and `$request->user()->role` and their datatypes..... because operators do not change their behaviour

Comment: perhaps == is sufficient

Comment: yes on hosting $status variable's type comes as string , but how is that possible same code how behaves like that

Comment: could be different php versions where functions changes their behavior

Comment: nope :S I tried it but nothing diffrent on local, I have used this operator on many file as === and i have to change all of them to == but i cant check if i miss one of them because they will not give any error on local i have to do this on hosting :S

Comment: We don't know the code that is used to generate $status, so we can't comment on why it should generate a string on one box and a numeric value on another

Comment: okay i got it,thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with the not identical comparison:

```
@if ($var !== 0)
```

The following code worked on both machines:

```
@if (($var != 0) || (is_null($var)))
```

I did not try it but inverting the logic should solve your problem:

```
if ((($status == 0) && (!is_null($status)) and ($request->user()->role!=1))
```

NOTE: You do not need to check for `NULL`in the second condition as it is converted to `0` and thus not equal.